# JDBC Derby: No funciona UNIQUE INDEX

Tags: javafx, derby

Creé una tabla de usuarios llamada "users" con índices únicos (id, username).

El problema es que puedo ingresar cualquier cantidad de "usernames" iguales y la base de datos no me retorna ningun error.

El índice único me aparece en la vista gráfica del IDE NetBeans, pero no me retorna los resultados esperados.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  username VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  role VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  -- seller || admin --
  password VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
  phone_number INTEGER,
  email VARCHAR(191),
  address VARCHAR(255),
  zip VARCHAR(8),
  created DATE,
  updated DATE,
  UNIQUE (id, username)
);

INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values
('admin','sadasdasd','admin'), -- username, password, role
('admin','asddfsg341','admin'), -- username, password, role
('admin','asdasdsa','admin'), -- username, password, role
('admin','asdsad131edsa','admin'), -- username, password, role
('admin','asda','admin'), -- username, password, role
('admin','135rqwdsa','admin'); -- username, password, role

select * from users
```

Como se puede verificar, en la sentencia SQL declaro claramente los campos único, pero aquí están los resultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el árbol lateral izquierdo de NetBeans se puede observar que los índices únicos se crearon "correctamente".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acaso me pase por alto algo?

PD: También intente crear la tabla y luego crear los índices aparte:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_username ON users(username, id)
```

Pero obtuve los mismos resultados.

Comment: Que gestor usas?

Comment: Derby-10.11 EmbeddedDriver